# Table of contents in Active report

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a active report. and i want to hide and edit the text of table of content text of table of content in active report 6 c# window form.

How to hide the thumbnail view pane in active report?

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the TOC you may access the TableOFContentsObject of the ActiveReoports Viewer and set it's properties in the manneras shown in the following documentation link :
[http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.TableOfContentsObject.html](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6%7EDataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.TableOfContentsObject.html)

However, please note that it is not possible to hide just one tab of the two. Both the tabs can be hidden or made [visible](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6%7EDataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.TableOfContentsObject%7EVisible.html) as a whole.

Regards,
Mohita